# Calculating time difference between IN row and OUT row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I stored in and out time as separate rows I am looking for a way to select in time and out time as two columns so I can count the total time spent based on in and out. so I have table like this

```
Time                          TimeType
2022-04-04 09:13:19.000         IN
2022-04-04 09:20:54.000         OUT
2022-04-04 09:21:54.000         IN
2022-04-04 09:25:54.000         OUT
2022-04-04 09:26:54.000         IN
2022-04-04 09:28:54.000         IN
```

I want to select and show as:

```
inTime                          outTime                   timeSpent
2022-04-04 09:13:19.000         2022-04-04 09:20:54.000    7
2022-04-04 09:21:54.000         2022-04-04 09:25:54.000    4
2022-04-04 09:26:54.000         NULL                       0
```

The NULL means it's error so any null values should be ignored Please let me know if there is any way to select them as above. Thanks

I tried like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT Times AS inTime FROM Table WHERE Times>='2022-09-29 00:00:00' AND Times<'2022-09-29 23:59:59' AND timeType='IN' AND personID='1'),
(SELECT Times AS outTime FROM Table WHERE Times>='2022-09-29 00:00:00' AND Times<'2022-09-29 23:59:59' AND timeType='OUT' AND personID='1')
```

but the above games be error because I can't select multiple rows.

then I tried join like this:

```
SELECT A.times AS inTime, B.times AS outTime FROM Table A
INNER JOIN Table B ON A.personID=B.personID
WHERE A.Times>='2022-04-04 00:00:00' AND A.Times<'2022-04-04 23:59:59' AND A.timeType='IN' AND A.personID='1' AND B.Times>='2022-04-04 00:00:00' AND B.Times<'2022-04-04 23:59:59' AND B.timeType='IN' AND B.personID='1'
```

the above join is repeating inTime and outtimes

Comment: For SQL Server - use PIVOT. For MySQL - conditional aggregation.

Comment: yes rows are always in pairs of 1 in and 1 out but only if there is any error so might be possible there will be 2 times in or 2 times out but in rare cases only. I that case I want one of the missing in/out should show blank (if possible)

Comment: I tried join and select same table twice as columns but no success

Comment: TimeSpent is not mandatory if it can be canculated from the select query that would be great otherwise in php loop I can calculate the timespent based on in and out times

Comment: TimeSpent is easy to calculate, we just need to know what units you want it in. As soon as you show us what you tried I'll help with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can just take advantage of the [`LEAD` analytic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to check the 'TimeType' from the next row to see if its a valid row (i.e. OUT follows IN) and if it is valid use `LEAD` to take the `Time` value from the next row and then calculate the difference. Finally filter out only IN rows.

```
declare @MyTable table ([Time] datetime2(3), TimeType varchar(3));

insert into @MyTable ([Time], TimeType)
values
('2022-04-03 09:13:19.000', 'IN'),
('2022-04-04 09:20:54.000', 'OUT'),
('2022-04-04 09:21:54.000', 'IN'),
('2022-04-04 09:25:54.000', 'OUT'),
('2022-04-04 09:26:54.000', 'IN'),
('2022-04-04 09:28:54.000', 'IN');

with cte as (
    select *
        , lead(TimeType) over (order by [Time] asc) LeadTimeType
        , lead([Time]) over (order by [Time] asc) OutTime
    from @MyTable
)
select [Time] InTime, OutTime
    , dateadd(second, datediff(second, [Time], OutTime), convert(time(3),'00:00:00.000')) TimeSpent
from cte
-- Either the IN row has a matching OUT row, or its the last 'IN' row
where (LeadTimeType != TimeType or LeadTimeType is null) and TimeType = 'IN'
order by [Time] asc;
```

Returns:

| InTime | OutTime | TimeSpent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-03 09:13:19.000 | 2022-04-04 09:20:54.000 | 00:07:35.000 |
| 2022-04-04 09:21:54.000 | 2022-04-04 09:25:54.000 | 00:04:00.000 |
| 2022-04-04 09:28:54.000 | NULL | NULL |

Note that adding your sample data as DDL+DML (as shown here) makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: what is RowIsOK  and LeadTimeType ?

Comment: @MzgksStudio checking that the next row after IN is OUT...  LeadTimeType  is the next rows TimeType... using the lead function... I suggest checking the documentation to gain an understanding.

Comment: why are you inserting the values ? the values are already there I just need to select them please let me know if I do not understand you properly.

Comment: I'm inserting the values so I can demonstrate the solution... and you should do the same when asking questions in future... I need to test the solution somehow, so I need actual sample data to test it.

Comment: @MzgksStudio thats your job to convert this solution to your actual data... this answers the question as asked. Now you get to tweak it as required to work on your live data.

Comment: I think I found from your suggestions what I really needed. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: the out time is not coming accurate, something is wrong could you please help ?

Comment: Ask a new question with a [mre]